# Unexpected response form IDMS Server

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, safari

I keep trying to login to the [Apple Community Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/community/ipad/using_ipad), but I get the error:

> Sorry, could not complete request because:
>   **Unexpected response form IDMS Server**

It will not let me log in. I'm on a MacBook Pro with El Capitan using Safari. I have tried closing Safari and reopening it, and restarting my computer. I am not having this problem on my iPad Pro 9.7".

What does this error message mean? Any suggestions on how to fix the problem so I can log into the Apple Community Forums from my MBP?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have resolved itself.